# Access a Variable of an Object from Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, visual-studio-2013, pass-by-reference

I need help with my c++ programm.
I start to Threads beside the main function:

```
thread Thread1(&Foo::Loop1, info,std::ref(info));
thread Thread2(&Foo::Loop2, info,std::ref(info));
```

`info` is an object from the class `Foo` which contains `bool active`

later I change the `active` to `true` but the value in `Loop1` or `Loop2` dont change. They are everytime the same.

my prototype function looks like this:

```
void Loop1(Foo info);
void Loop2(Foo info);
```

the called function:

```
void Foo::Loop1(Foo info){
    while (true){
        if (info.active){
          //Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So what should I do to pass the value from the object `Foo` which change in the `main` function so the value `active` in the `Loop` functions are equal.

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the functions are static members, they should have a reference parameter, `Foo&`.

```
void Loop1(Foo& info);
void Loop2(Foo& info);
```

otherwise the threads get copies of the object you passed.

If they are non-static members you don't need to pass the instance at all:

```
void Foo::Loop1(){
    while (true){
        if (active){
          //Stuff
        }
    }
}

thread Thread1(&Foo::Loop1, info);
thread Thread2(&Foo::Loop2, info);
```

Comment: sry but both didnt worked :/ the thread only pass the Value and not the reference. I tried multiple things :/

Comment: ok got it :) used std::ref when created the thread and as param. i used Foo& info like your example

Answer (score 0):

`std::ref` returns an `std::reference_wrapper<T>` which is implicitly convertable to `T&` via its conversion operator.  When you pass an `std::reference_wrapper<T>` to a function which accepts a `T` by value, the conversion operator is invoked, and the function's local copy of `T` is constructed via its copy constructor.

```
#include <functional>

class Object
{
    // ...
};

void Func(Object obj)
{
    // Some code which modifies obj
}

int main()
{
    Object obj;
    Func(std::ref(obj));  // <-- Conversion operator invoked, obj passed by value
}
```

Change the functions to accept `Foo` by reference.